# Java Change JButton Color with Method

Tags: java, swing, methods, colors, jbutton

I've implemented a `JFrame` with 25 `JButton` components to represent the available rooms in a hotel. I do know this is not the whole program but how can I create a method in which when pressed the color changes?

The colors for available rooms is green and I would like to change them to red.

Comment: You seem to be talking about a JToggleButton

Answer (score 1):

This code uses a `JToggleButton` with different colored icons for standard & selected states. A `JCheckBox` might also be used.

[image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;

public class RoomReservationToggle {

    private JComponent ui = null;
    private String reservedPath = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/xj49g.png";
    private String freePath = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/zJ8am.png";

    RoomReservationToggle() {
        try {
            initUI();
        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void initUI() throws MalformedURLException {
        if (ui != null) {
            return;
        }
        ui = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 4, 4, 4));
        ui.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(4, 4, 4, 4));

        ImageIcon reservedIcon = new ImageIcon(new URL(reservedPath));
        ImageIcon freeIcon = new ImageIcon(new URL(freePath));

        Random r = new Random();
        for (int ii = 1; ii < 17; ii++) {
            // a JCheckBox might also be used
            JToggleButton tb = new JToggleButton(freeIcon, r.nextBoolean());
            tb.setSelectedIcon(reservedIcon);
            ui.add(tb);
        }
    }

    public JComponent getUI() {
        return ui;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (Exception useDefault) {
                }
                RoomReservationToggle o = new RoomReservationToggle();

                JFrame f = new JFrame(o.getClass().getSimpleName());
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                f.setLocationByPlatform(true);

                f.setContentPane(o.getUI());
                f.pack();
                f.setMinimumSize(f.getSize());

                f.setVisible(true);
            }
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the methods `setForeground()` and `setBackground()` to change colours.

Make sure you call these methods from the event thread/queue.

Your configured L&F can ignore these however. Sometimes calling `setOpaque(true)` might help in those cases.

Comment: The problem with buttons is, they don't always honour the background color property, at least not in away you might expect